# RESTful outside HTTP protocol

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I understand that **REST** is the recommended architectural style for the web, which basically works on HTTP protocol. I am wondering if there is **RESTful architecture** applied in other protocols like **TCP** or **custom** one. Can someone point me to an application that embodies such a characteristic or, or explain if RESTful is just for HTTP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: REST can work over anything. HTTP is just a transport mechanism. If you can get data from point A to point B, and from point B to point A, then you can use REST.

Comment: Remote Procedure Calls existed long time ago. You could use *RPC/XDR* or *Corba* , etc...

Comment: HTTP is often used over TCP, they belong to entirely different layers. As for your question, the principles of REST can be applied to virtually any protocol but all RESTful apps I know are based on HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation guys. I am wondering if any one knows such an application; so that I can check it out.

Comment: @Marc I suspect that's not quite the whole story; REST does place some requirements on the underlying protocol (I suspect it falls apart without the requests supplying a verb, or if there's no possibility of doing content type negotiation) so the “REST can work over anything” probably ought to be constrained. (I'd hate to see someone do REST over the finger protocol, and doing it over XMPP would remind me of doing SOAP over HTTP but in reverse…)

Comment: @donal: if you can do [TCPoAC](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1149.txt) then REST-on-finger should be a piece of cake.

Comment: @Marc For my sins, I've tunneled SOAP over XMPP over a VPN over BLOAT (because of a horrible retarded proxy run by Mordac's kid brother at this site where we were running an important demo) but that doesn't make it right to have high levels of nesting. Let's use the minimum amount of crap to make things work, OK?

Comment: @Abraham I couldn't find any REST implementation that's not HTTP based. My use case was for communication between private service applications, Netflix seems to be using some sort of lightweight HTTP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTTP  protocol  maps the restful resources to the service. If you really keen to do the coding stuff and address the TCP transport layer you might get little performance advantage.
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344512/Building-and-Testing-WCF-RESTful-services) is link for a project which has done with some similarities

But I think for the development easiness you better stick to the HTTP.